# Gravity form image retrieve in mail template

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I want to retrieve image in mail notification or template using gravity form. I used radio button for image selection. I used `{imageradio::50}` to retrieve it but it can not retrieve in mail notification how can i do this?  {imageradio::50} is a key & value for radio button.